# Need help styling MaterialUI MenuItem Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-in-js

I'm attempting to style a menu item using the MaterialUI framework, and feeling lost.

Here's what I'm going for:

[image]

And, here's what I've got, so far: https://codesandbox.io/s/542wvq4mxl

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I'm seeing is that the `MenuItem` component has a `padding` applied. But what you're trying to do is have the orange background of the icon stretch the full height ignoring this padding (or, alternatively, have the white background of the text and arrow do the same). There may be a css way to do this but I'm not aware of it.

So I'd try removing the default padding on your `menuItem` class and add the spacing back in yourself, like https://codesandbox.io/s/z6q4z54njp

Answer (score 1):

Change your style to following.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  menuItem: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    height: "50px",
    fontSize: "50px"
  },
  primary: {
    height: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    fontSize: "30px"
  },
  icon: {
    fill: "#ffff",
    backgroundColor: "#ff6b30",
    width: "70px",
    height: "70px"
  }
});
```